# UITextField becomeFirstReponder not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I am newish to iOS development and have gone through tutorials using Objective-C but am now trying Swift. Anyway, I am writing an app and have a bar button item that segues to another view which has three UITextFields on it. When the user taps inside the first UITextField I want to the keyboard to popup. I use an action to trigger this and issue a becomeFirstResponder() on the UITextField. I have also tried doing this in the ViewDidAppear delegate and the keyboard won't popup. I have tried this only on the simulator using iPhone 4s, and iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1 as I don't yet have a key to run it on a device (i'm cheap).

Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class testViewController : UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
@IBAction func textEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.canResignFirstResponder() == true &&
        text.window != nil &&
        text.canBecomeFirstResponder() == true &&
        text.becomeFirstResponder() == true
    {
        NSLog("Did set responder\n")
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog("Failed setting text as first responder")
    }
}
@IBAction func doneAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    text.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The focus does switch to the first UITextField when becomeFirstResponder() is called in viewDidAppear.

Any ideas. I did search through many posts to an answer and non of their solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type using your physical keyboard, does your input go to your text field as you expect? In the iOS8 simulator, the keyboard is hidden by default. See `Hardware -> Keyboard` settings on your iOS Simulator.

Comment: Yes, if I enable the keyboard via cmd+k it pops up. and when I leave the view or app, it pops up again. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to type with the computers keyboard, it means the 'becomeFirstResponder' has been issued, iOS 8 hides the keyboard by default on a simulator, that might be the reason why you can't see the keyboard pop out